# C++11 Compiler compatibility table

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, cross-platform

I'm working on a rather large library that I'm designing to be portable across compilers and platforms. The main language being used is C++11, however I'm trying to provide fallbacks using preprocessor macros for compilers that do not yet provide full conformance.

GCC has a full list of all the [supported/unsupported C++11 features](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), along with the version in which they first provided support for it -- however I can't seem to find any equivalent listing for MSVC. In fact, the only tables I can find that list support, strictly list the [Visual Studios version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) in which it was first introduced, but not the MSVC version.

So my question is: What is the internal version number in which support is first introduced for C++11 features in MSVC? I find it hard to imagine that changes are only made every full version release.

If there isn't an answer for this, would that mean I'd have to target it based on the Visual Studio version? If so, how can I translate the version based strictly by its name to the internal `__MSC_VER` and `__MSC_FULL_VER`?

**Edit:**

Just to clarify, I'm trying to make it so that I can detect when specific C++11 features were implemented in Visual Studios. For example, with gcc, `constexpr` was introduced in version 4.6, which allows for me to check with:

```
#if (__GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 6))
// Do something
#endif
```

Ideally, I'm trying to do the same thing using `__MSC_VER`. The issue is simply that I don't know the versions which each feature were added in, short of each major version release.

Comment: @Bitwise- Your question is a good one, but as it read originally, it sounded like it was asking for an off-site resource. This sort of question is off-topic, as is mentioned in the [help]. I changed it so it is looking for an answer, not a link to the answer itself. Hopefully that helps, and feel free to change it back if it doesn't.

Comment: Downvoter- care to share why? This question is asking about "software tools commonly used by programmers", which is described in the [help/on-topic] as being on topic.

Comment: @BlueIce - I'm fine with the new wording because it works better with the rules (I didn't even think to check for that one, sorry!), however what I'm trying to find is each internal version in which a new feature has been added. For example, `constexpr` support was included in GCC 4.6 -- allowing a macro detection of `#if __GNUC__ >= 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 6)`, but I can't find any equivalent for MSVC

Comment: Gotcha. Your edit seems to fix the problem, and hopefully you will find an answer soon :)

Comment: You could have a look at how other libraries detect those features, e.g. websocketpp: https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp

Comment: @Bitwize: You want `(__GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 6))`, not `>=4`.

Comment: @jPlatte That's sorta what I've been doing, but I've been mainly trying to figure out where they got their version numbers from so I can implement it myself without always having to find other libraries that did so as well. 

It's starting to look (from comments to other unrelated questions) like MSVC doesn't update their minor version number often, meaning a check strictly for the studio version should be sufficient.

Comment: @MSalters Good catch! I was writing that off the top of my head and must have slipped up.

Comment: Well, how about asking  the people who wrote the libraries that do these checks already? :D